# Testing the ACTUAL batchable context in Database.Batchable methods?

Tags: apex, batch, asynchronous, asyncapexjob, context

I'm trying to mock Database.BatchableContext to make my unit tests more robust and to eliminate excess usage of Test.isRunningTest() running in production code. Few hacks are available like `Json.deserialize('{"jobId":""}', Database.BatchableContextImpl.class)` but feels bad.

My batch class implementation is boring and ordinary:

```
public class LongWalksOnTheBatch implements Database.Batchable {

    public Iterable start(context) {...}

    public void execute(context, scopes) {...}

    public void finish(context) {...}

}
```

And most of the time, these techniques are sufficient:

1. Using Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() to run 1 iteration:

   ```
   //arrange
   Database.Batchable batch = new LongWalksOnTheBatch();

   //act
   Test.startTest();
   Database.executeBatch(batch, 1);
   Test.stopTest();

   //assert
   System.assert(sideEffects);
   ```
2. Manually calling the execute() method to observe more complex behaviours:

   ```
   //arrange
   Database.Batchable batch = new LongWalksOnTheBatch();

   //act
   batch.execute(null, new List<SObject>());
   batch.execute(null, new List<SObject>());
   batch.execute(null, new List<SObject>());

   //assert
   System.assert(sideEffects);
   ```

But this gets a bit crap when that Database.BatchableContext is *actually* needed. For example to abort the job. But trying to getJobId() will result in a big fat NullPointerException. So what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code compiles indicating `Database.BatchableContext` is an interface:

```
public class MockBatchableContext implements Database.BatchableContext {
    private Id jobId;
    private Id childJobId;
    public MockBatchableContext(Id jobId, Id childJobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
        this.childJobId = childJobId;
    }
    public Id getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }
    public Id getChildJobId() {
        return childJobId;
    }     
}
```

so in your technique 2) you can avoid the NPE by passing in an instance of such a class. But you would still have to guard any [System.abortJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_abortJob) calls by checking `Test.isRunningTest()`.

Comment: This is great, Keith!!! Undocumented but totally a goer :D

Comment: The exception thrown by System.abortJob() can be caught in the test, as a proxy to signal the abort was attempted :-) `System.StringException: Job does not exist or is already aborted`